# Deadlock with anonymous mutex and struct

Tags: go, struct, mutex, deadlock, embedding

Let's say I have these two structs:

```
type A struct {
    Mutex sync.Mutex
    i int
}

type B struct {
    A
    sync.Mutex
}
```

Now, when I try to lock `B` and then `A` I got a deadlock:

```
var b B
b.Lock()
b.Mutex.Lock()
b.Mutex.Unlock()
b.Unlock()
```

I figured out that this is related with the name of the mutex of the struct `A`, for example, there is no deadlock if I name it `Mutexx` and not `Mutex`. But I don't know why it matters. Can anyone, please, explain this behavior?

https://play.golang.org/p/UVi_WLWeGmi

Comment: Just for interest sake this is an implementation of counting recursive locks: http://github.com/jwells131313/goethe

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason for the deadlock is because your code will call the `Lock()` method of the same mutex twice, which is a blocking operation.

The explanation lies in [Spec: Selectors:](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Selectors)

> The following rules apply to selectors:
>
> 1. For a value `x` of type `T` or `*T` where `T` is not a pointer or interface type, `x.f` denotes the field or method at the **shallowest** depth in `T` where there is such an `f`. If there is not exactly [one `f`](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Uniqueness_of_identifiers) with shallowest depth, the selector expression is illegal.

What does this mean?

In `B`, you embed both a `sync.Mutex` and a value of `A`, and `A` also embeds a `sync.Mutex`.

When you write `B.Mutex`, that could refer to the directly embedded `B.Mutex` field (the unqualified type name acts as the field name), and *could* also refer to `B.A.Mutex` (because the `A` field is embedded in `B`), but according to the quoted rule above, it will denote the field / method at the *shallowest* depth which is `B.Mutex`.

Similarly, `b.Lock()` could refer to `B.Mutex.Lock()` and could refer to `B.A.Mutex.Lock()`. But again according to the quoted rule, it will denote the field / method at the *shallowest* depth, which is `B.Mutex.Lock()`.

So this code:

```
b.Lock()
b.Mutex.Lock()
```

Will call the `Lock()` method of the same `Mutex` twice, which is the embedded `B.Mutex` field of the `B` struct. The 2nd call will block, as the mutex is already locked.

When you rename `A.Mutex` to e.g. `A.Mutexx`, and then you write:

```
b.Lock()
b.Mutexx.Lock()
```

The first `b.Lock()` call refers to `B.Mutex.Lock()`, and the second `b.Mutexx.Lock()` call refers to `B.A.Mutexx.Lock()` call, so they lock 2 different, distinct mutexes; they are independent, so the 2nd lock will not block (its mutex is not yet locked).

Comment: Yep, thanks. In fact, I just didn't knew that it's possible to access anonymous field by the name of its type. The part of the spec describing this would be enough.

Comment: @vonaka That is in [Spec: Struct types:](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Struct_types) _"A field declared with a type but no explicit field name is called an embedded field. An embedded field must be specified as a type name `T` or as a pointer to a non-interface type name `*T`, and `T` itself may not be a pointer type. **The unqualified type name acts as the field name.**"_